# Mysql search query sorting by brand and sum brand value

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hi I am trying to run a query where `brand_name` should be `distinct` but the `brand_value` show `sum`. `Mysql` `TABLE` structure with `Primary key`

`betbingo  1 www.abc.com`
`betbingo  1 www.abc.com`
`betbingo  2 www.abc.com`
`bestbingo 2 www.abc.com`
`bestbingo 1 www.abc.com`
`bet365    1 www.abc.com`

I want brand column distinct and show sum of 2nd column. So the result should be like this

`Betbingo  4 www.abc.com`
`bestbingo 3 www.abc.com`
`bet365    1 www.abc.com`

I am using While loop in php
Can you please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far ? Kindly show us some query ..

Comment: Show us the coedz pliz

Comment: I recomend that you do all the heavy lifting in your sql query instead of on the php side. @pirate has a sample below and i pasted a sqlfiddle in the comment there

Comment: Sorry for late reply.    $sql ="SELECT * FROM ftd WHERE ftddate BETWEEN CAST('$startdate' AS DATE) AND CAST('$enddate' AS DATE) AND (website='$website')";

Comment: i am searching by date and by website, now its showing me all brands and  values... i just want to show unique brand and the total values as i mentioned above

Comment: Thanks Guys... its sorted :) select brand, sum(2nd column) from your_table group by brand... This query worked for me :)

Comment: then accept the answer and vote up. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group by clause. It will select distinct brand name from your table.

```
select brand, sum(2nd column) from your_table group by brand
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aca37/1/0 i didn't want to replicate an an answer since you beat me to it

Comment: The OP has yet to post anything additional in the way of code. I am assuming from the way the question was phrased that he was approaching this from the php side instead of sql side.

Comment: yeah, may be, question is not clear. but it is easy using sql.

Answer (score -1):

Not clear about the primary key but group by and sum() in the sql should do the trick

Select brand , sum(brand_value) as sum_of_brandvalue from tablename group by brand ;